# Open ports on mac. Safe?

Tags: ports

My friend is currently running the default firewall on his mac with "Block all incoming connection" (except the basic ones like 80). I just scanned his mac for open ports and I found the following:

```
 Open TCP Port:     3128        ndl-aas
 Open TCP Port:     8080        http-alt
```

Is it normal to have those ports open, or does he have something fuzzy installed?

Answer (score 2):

Well, "block all incoming connections" should *block all incoming connections* so you should not be able to find *any* open port. Note that even port 80 ought not be open either: a typical desktop system has no business running a Web server itself.

The fact that there are open ports is indicative that the "block all incoming connections" setting does not work as expected. Port 3128 is a traditional port of an HTTP proxy.

What you report does not add up. Either the Mac runs some servers, does not block incoming connections, and could be under active external hostile control. Or maybe you made a typing error and you are not scanning the machine you believe you are scanning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It actually says block all incoming connections, but underneath it says except services like DHCP, IPsec and so on. Thanks for the info about port 80, didn't knew that. Do you have any info about 8080? Should it be open, or is it like port 80?

Comment: And one other thing. I scanned the computer from the computer itself. Does that change the result? I used a tool similar to nmap.

Comment: One more thing. I'm not running anything similar to a server. Just surfing the web and stuff.

Comment: Oh yes, it changes quite a lot of things. "Incoming connections blocking" is usually applied on connections _from the outside_. By scanning from the machine itself you are seeing the services that the machine runs _for itself_, which are bound to `localhost`. If you want to see what the machine runs, try `netstat -an` and look at the "LISTEN" lines. If you want to see what outsiders see from the machine, you must do the scan from their position, i.e. outside. On another machine.